# Having issue with rectangle drawing function not working when called a second time with new parameters

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that creates an array of numbers that read out as a PGM image file. I can get the program to write out to a text file with one instance of the rectangle function working, but not the second instance. I can't figure out why the second instance of the function isn't altering the array as well. Is it something wrong with the print function or rectangle function? Any point in the right direction is appreciated, after three hours of videos I'm at a loss.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200;
const int IMAGE_WIDTH = 300;
const int GREY_SCALE = 255;

const int RECT1_TOP = 10;
const int RECT1_LEFT = 10;
const int RECT1_HEIGHT = 25;
const int RECT1_WIDTH = 50;
const int RECT1_GREY = 255;

const int RECT2_TOP = 50;
const int RECT2_LEFT = 30;
const int RECT2_HEIGHT = 25;
const int RECT2_WIDTH = 50;
const int RECT2_GREY = 200;

void createImage(unsigned char image[][IMAGE_WIDTH], int height);

bool writeImage(const unsigned char image[][IMAGE_WIDTH], int height);

void drawRect(unsigned char image[][IMAGE_WIDTH],
              int imgHeight,
              int rectTop,
              int rectLeft,
              int rectHeight,
              int rectWidth,
              unsigned char grayLevel);

int main()
{

    unsigned char image[IMAGE_HEIGHT][IMAGE_WIDTH] = { };

    createImage(image, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    writeImage(image, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    return 0;
}

void createImage(unsigned char image[][IMAGE_WIDTH], int height)
{
    drawRect(image,
             height,
             RECT1_TOP,
             RECT1_LEFT,
             RECT1_HEIGHT,
             RECT1_WIDTH,
             RECT1_GREY);

    drawRect(image,
             height,
             RECT2_TOP,
             RECT2_LEFT,
             RECT2_HEIGHT,
             RECT2_WIDTH,
             RECT2_GREY);
}

void drawRect(unsigned char image[][IMAGE_WIDTH],
              int imgHeight,
              int rectTop,
              int rectLeft,
              int rectHeight,
              int rectWidth,
              unsigned char grayLevel)
{
    for (int rectRow = rectTop; rectRow < rectHeight; rectRow++)
    {
        for (int rectCol = rectLeft; rectCol < rectWidth; rectCol++)
            image[rectRow][rectCol] = { grayLevel };
    }
}

bool writeImage(const unsigned char image[][IMAGE_WIDTH], int height)
{
    ofstream makeShapes;

    makeShapes.open("makeShapes.txt");

    makeShapes << "P2 \n";
    makeShapes << IMAGE_WIDTH << " " << height << "\n";
    for (int imageRow = 0; imageRow < height; imageRow++)
    {
        for (int imageColumn = 0; imageColumn < IMAGE_WIDTH; imageColumn++)
            makeShapes << static_cast<int>(image[imageRow][imageColumn]) << ' ';
        makeShapes << endl;
    }

    makeShapes.close();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know if people copy pasted the code into visual studios or read it directly from the website. I should have taken the time to properly format it. It should be better now.

Comment: How exactly do you expect to end up with the second image saved, somewhere, when the function that writes the image always writes to the same file, so obviously the second image will end up simply overwriting the first one?

Comment: How would I make it so that both instances of calling the rectangle funciton just replaced zero placeholder values in the specified areas of the array?

Comment: Default open behaviour for an `ofstream` is to write over the file, not append to it. [Read this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) and pick the appropriate mode.

Comment: `for (int rectRow = rectTop; rectRow < rectHeight; rectRow++)` Wouldn't the end condition for this be `rectTop + rectHeight`? Same for width.

Comment: You are correct. Can't believe I didn't see that earlier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you've missed a piece of data in writing out the file. After the width and height you need to add the maximum  value a channel can take. So your file output should be something like:

```
P2
300 200
255
<...image data...>
```

Next, you're passing in the rectangle's width and height to `drawRect`, but it's treating them as if they were the right and bottom of the rectangle. When you pass in 25 and 50 for the height and width, the left and top are already greater than that, so the outer loop doesn't even execute once. You need to make your loop in `drawRect` like this:

```
for (int rectRow = rectTop; rectRow < rectTop + rectHeight; rectRow++)
{
    for (int rectCol = rectLeft; rectCol < rectLeft + rectWidth; rectCol++)
        image[rectRow][rectCol] = { grayLevel };
}
```

Comment: It's also generally recommended that the lines in the file aren't any longer than 70ish columns, but I haven't noticed any modern image handling software being too strict about that.

Comment: This got the code to work the way I intended. I guess i just didn't realize where my actual starting point was with my code. Thank you for pointing out my error!